# What is the difference between redirect and forward in Symfony?

Tags: redirect, symfony1

I want to know the difference between :

```
$this->forward("module", "action");
```

And

```
$this->redirect("module/action");
```

My first guess is that one implies a new request while the other one not, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In some cases, the action execution ends by requesting a new action execution. For instance, an action handling a form submission in a `POST` request usually redirects to another action after updating the database. Another example is an action alias: the index action is often a way to display a list, and actually forwards to a list action.

The action class provides two methods to execute another action:

If the action forwards the call to another action:

```
$this->forward('otherModule', 'index');
```

If the action results in a web redirection:

```
$this->redirect('otherModule/index');
$this->redirect('http://www.google.com/');
```

The choice between a redirect or a forward is sometimes tricky. To choose the best solution, keep in mind that a forward is internal to the application and transparent to the user. As far as the user is concerned, the displayed URL is the same as the one requested. In contrast, a redirect is a message to the user's browser, involving a new request from it and a change in the final resulting URL.

If the action is called from a submitted form with `method="post"`, you should always do a redirect. The main advantage is that if the user refreshes the resulting page, the form will not be submitted again; in addition, the back button works as expected by displaying the form and not an alert asking the user if he wants to resubmit a `POST` request.

Comment: This is the orginal text from [Symfony Docu](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_0/06-Inside-the-Controller-Layer#chapter_06_sub_skipping_to_another_action), you should had named at least your source ! @e-satis

Comment: why are you pinging me @domi27 ?

Comment: @e-satis only to provide full documentation about your topic !

Comment: well that is really good answer, but how come forwarding works and redirection doesnt on some application which has authentication process in it ?